# Find all the solutions $(x,y,z)$ $\in \Bbb Z^+$ such that $(x+1)^y-x^z=1$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

Find all the solutions $(x,y,z)$ $\in \Bbb Z^+$ such that $(x+1)^y-x^z=1$.

This is an old problem from a math olympiad in Venezuela, in the year 2000.

I don't know how to start solving this kind of problem, and i didn't found any solution yet in internet, i only found the problem.

The only thing i tried was to manipulate the equation:
$$(x+1)^y-x^z=1$$
$$(x+1)^y=1+x^z$$

and after that maybe use the Binomial theorem, but i think it doesn't work.

Edit: It's trivial that $y=z=1$ makes infinite solutions for any value of $x$, but what happens to $x,y,z \gt 1$ ?

Any hints?.

Comment: Reduce the equation mod $x+1$ and infer that $z$ is odd. Prove that $x+1$ divides $z$ with the proper factorization. Then use LTE to show that $(x+1)^{y-1}|z$.

Comment: I'd start with pure reasoning. if y = z =1, the equation is correct for every x. if this is bot the case, we can at least deduce that z>y has to be true if we want to find other solutions. furthermore notice if y=1 we get x+1=1+x^z so infinitely many solutions again, with x=1 and z in Z. from there you can carry on to deduce the other solutions.